# What's wrong with the MAX() when applying for Datetime?

Tags: php, mysql

i have not ideal what happen on this.

this is working fine

```
SELECT 
SUM(LAMT)AS SUMAMT, 
COUNT(LAMT)AS CNT, 
IFNULL(LSUBDT,(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 9999 DAY))AS MXDT 
FROM product1 
WHERE LSUBBY IN (12,15,17,13,14,16) AND RECST=1 ORDER BY LSUBDT
```

it return me (which is fineZ) 
SUMAMT > 645746.00
CNT > 4
MXDT > 2012-11-14 15:56:56

**BUT**
when i using **MAX(IFNULL(LSUBDT,(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 9999 DAY)))AS MXDT**
it return me
MXDT > 323031322d31312d32332030353a30323a3037

WHY? i cant use it to do compare in php when using strtotime

1). what's wrong with the sql MAX()?
2). Any alternative beside MAX()? i want get the latest DATETIME.
3). can some where some how php CONVERT it back to 2012-11-14 15:56:56 format then i continue in php compare later

**By the way**
4). the return result of MXDT > 2012-11-14 15:56:56 also is not correct coz in the database the latest datetime is 2012-11-24 5:36:25, if i remove the sum and the count then it return me correctly.

thanks

Comment: An alternative is surely to order by the datetime field and then limit the number of rows to 1.

Comment: What are you using to connect to the database? It looks like something is converting the results to hex before handing it to you, `323031322d31312d32332030353a30323a3037` is `2012-11-23 05:02:07`.

Comment: $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die (mysql_error());

$dbname = 'database_name';
mysql_select_db($dbname)or die(mysql_error());

Comment: Joni, then how to convert from hex back to date,time

Comment: my own solution as this.... IFNULL(MAX(LSUBDT),(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 9999 DAY))AS MXDT, adding MAX(LSUBDT)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT SUM(SUMAMT)AS SUMAMT, SUM(CNT)AS CNT, MAX(MXDT) AS MXDT 
from (SELECT SUM(LAMT)AS SUMAMT, COUNT(LAMT)AS CNT, 
             IFNULL(LSUBDT,(CURDATE()-INTERVAL 9999 DAY)) AS MXDT 
      FROM (SELECT LAMT, LSUBDT FROM product1 
            WHERE LSUBBY IN (12,15,17,13,14,16) AND RECST=1 ORDER BY LSUBDT DESC 
     ) AS A GROUP BY LSUBDT
) AS B
```